# Difference 2.8 and 2.9

Tags: versions

Not new to 3D, 25+ years in various applications. Now switching to Blender. I am wondering if the UI difference is too big to buy training classes that are in 2.8 and do them in 2.9? In other words, will I waste a lot of time because things have switched between 2.8 and 2.9?

Thanks!

Comment: Big jump occoured between 2.79 an 2.8, there is not much difference between 2.8 and 2.9 series... depending on what the classes are about you can have some changes, but my bet would be that 95% of the things you will learn will still be vaild. That said, for a proper answer, you'll have to provide more information about the courses.

Comment: Thanks @Carlo ! I am specifically looking at following trainings:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6
https://cgcookie.com/lesson/welcome-to-the-blender-basics
https://www.udemy.com/course/blender-29-3d-model-render-a-stylized-halloween-scene/
https://www.linkedin.com/learning/blender-2-83-essential-training

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To conclude this. I was able to track most of the courses if they were in Blender above 2.8. In general if you buy training, they are more likely to update their content to later versions of Blender UI.

I went through a lot of courses by https://www.cgfasttrack.com/ and watched a lot of videos from various people on Youtube. Whereoff i’d like to point out Joe which is running https://youtube.com/c/CGFigures on youtube. Especially helpful if you’re looking for medical animations. Lately I am
Going through everything I can from Erindale on youtube https://youtube.com/c/Erindale which is very helpful if you’re looking for all things procedural.